# What's the hypercorrect way to phrase a sentence with two 'for's in a row?

Tags: word-order, prepositional-phrases

Some backstory: It was the Friday before Valentine's day, and I walked into a classroom to find a pile of Hershey's Kisses left for someone in the class. Initially, I wanted to take one, but then I quipped, `I'll leave it for whoever it's for`, with the first 'for' reflecting my intention and the second 'for' indicating the pile's rightful owner.

Now I'm wondering, what's the 'hypercorrect' (i.e. doesn't end with prepositions, etc.) way to structure a sentence with two identical prepositions? The best I could do was, `I'll leave it for for whomever it is`, but this sounds silly to me with the two 'for's together.

Comment: Does the sentence **really need** two *for*s at all?

Comment: "I'll leave it for whoever it is (meant for)." Even, "I'll leave it for whoever (it is meant for)."

Comment: The simplest way around that difficulty you present would be: I'll leave it **TO** whoever it's for.

Comment: It's not really incorrect to end a sentence with a preposition. If you can't stand to do it, how about "I'll leave it for whomever it was intended."

Comment: You may want to look up the word [*hypercorrection*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hypercorrection).

Comment: *I'll leave it for whomever it's meant.*

Comment: @LittleEva I seriously suspect that ***to*** will change the whole meaning of the clause; it cannot be a substitute for *for*.

Comment: @Kris: to: 2. identifying the person or thing affected. see, Wikipedia. Your example: "I'll leave the Hershey's Kisses for whoever it is (meant for)." Or, my example: "I'll leave the Hershey's Kisses to whomever they were meant for." No semantic difference and not ungrammatical. :-)

Comment: @Kris - My hardcover Merriam-Webster New Collegiate: **to**: **7a**.3 to indicate the receiver of an action or the one for which something is done or exists <spoke to his father>< **gives a dollar to the man** > and often used with a reflexive pronoun to indicate  exclusiveness (as of possession) or separateness <had the house to them selves><thought to himself>.

Comment: @Kris - So it would appear that you are correct, my usage *does* change the meaning because it requires a possession <I gave  Hershey's Kisses to whomever they were meant for> the subject does not have. Unfortunately for me, I have used that erroneous formulation all of my life. I'm mortified. So sorry. :-(

Answer (score 1):

"I will leave it for its intended recipient, whoever that might be."

Answer (score -2):

> I'll leave it for whomever for whom it is.

It's a silly rule, however, to not allow prepositions at the end.